Solving ODEs with power series method Airy's equation
Once you've found the recurrence relation relating say for example $$ a_{k+2}=\frac{a_{k-1}}{(k+2)(k+1)}$$ in Airy's equation, and after finding pattern for $a_{3n}$ and $a_{3n+1}$, i.e $$ a_{3n} = \frac{a_{0}}{(2)(3)(5)(6)...(3n-1)(3n)}$$ and $$ a_{3n+1} = \frac{a_{1}}{(3)(4)(6)(7) \ldots (3n)(3n+1)}$$ is $n=1, 2, 3, \ldots$ here or does it start from $0$?
I think it's the former because for $n=0$ I get $a_0$ and $a_1$ which are free parameters depending on the initial conditions, so $n=1, 2, 3, \ldots$?

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AiryDifferentialEquation.html

Before asking any questions, search it in approach zero website, link : https://approach0.xyz/search/
